# Creating a "good vibes only" Twitter feed

Tags: twitter, data-science, streaming

As the title suggests, I want to create a filtered Twitter based on the sentiment of the tweets in my feed.

I believe I can do the first bit of obtaining the Twitter data and then running a ML model from Hugging Face. I've done that using Quix and this tutorial (https://quix.io/how-to-build-no-code-pipeline-sentiment-analysis/) But I don't know whether I have the ability to publish the feed to a web application.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated! FYI I'm very junior!!